# What can I deduce about this daily Skyscrapers? (Mar. 18, 2024, 5x5 Easy)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

So I have been using a site called [Brain Bashers](https://www.brainbashers.com/puzzles.asp), which is a site filled with logical deduction puzzles, because I like trying to master different logical deduction puzzle types.

I have finished the first two Skyscrapers puzzles currently working on the 5x5 (Easy) Daily Skyscrapers. This is the puzzle:

```
    3   2   2   3   1
  +---+---+---+---+---+
4 |   |   |   |   |   | 1
  +---+---+---+---+---+
2 |   |   |   |   |   | 2
  +---+---+---+---+---+
2 |   |   |   |   |   | 2
  +---+---+---+---+---+
1 |   |   |   |   |   | 5
  +---+---+---+---+---+
2 |   |   |   |   |   | 3
  +---+---+---+---+---+
    2   3   1   2   4
```

This is my progress so far on this puzzle:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Note: A missing number means that the number is already satisfied|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
            2   3
  +---+---+---+---+---+
4 | 2 | 3 |   |   | 5 |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
  | 1 | 5 |   |   |   | 2
  +---+---+---+---+---+
2 | 4 | 2 |   |   |   | 2
  +---+---+---+---+---+
  | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
2 | 3 | 1 |   |   |   | 3
  +---+---+---+---+---+
            1   2   4
```

My question: What could I deduce right now from here about this puzzle? I know I could probably solve it as sort of a 5x5 KenKen, but I want to know what I could deduce the solution from how it is actually supposed to solved.

Comment: Column 3 looks very constrained.

Comment: So does column 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Columns**

- From the bottom of column 3, you can see only a single stack.  That must mean the 5 is in the bottom-most row (otherwise you would be able to see it behind whatever other value was there).
- From the bottom of column 4, you can see two stacks.  That means that 1 and 5 are not possibilities for the bottow row, because you would see either >2 or 1 stacks respectively with those values.  That leaves 3 and 4.  3 is already in that row, so the only possible number remaining is 4.
- From the bottom of column 5, you can see 4 stacks.  That means at least 3 stacks must be visible behind whatever you put into the bottow row.  Thus you obviously need to put the 2 there, so that there are still 3 bigger numbers behind it.

**Rows**

- From the right of row 2, you know you will be able to see the 5, and you only need to see one more, so the 4 must go in the rightmost column. (Otherwise you would see 5, 4, and whatever is to the right of 4.)  That leaves 3 and 2, which can only be arranged one way so as not to conflict with row 4.
- From the right of row 5, you can see 3 stacks.  You know won't be able to see the 3 or the 1 at the left of the row, because a 5 has to go in there somewhere, and it will block both of them.  But you still need to be able to see 3 stacks, so the 5 must go as far to the left as possible, and then the remaining numbers in descending order.